# how can i perform $set with a variable on mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

how can i query mongodb using a variable

here is my cart.service looks like

```
const arrayFilters = {
  arrayFilters: [{ 'item._id': itemId }],
};

const conditions = {
  userId: userId,
  'items._id': itemId,
};

const query = { $set: {} };
if (total && totalPoint && qty) {
  query.$set['items.$[item].qty'] = qty;
  query.$set['items.$[item].total'] = total;
  query.$set['items.$[item].totalPoint'] = totalPoint;
}

if (notes) {
  query.$set['items.$[item].notes'] = notes;
}
```

and here is my repository looks like

```
await this.cartModel
  .findOneAndUpdate(conditions, query, arrayFilters)
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    throw new Error(err);
  });
```

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: aahh.. already solved, it's 3am last night so i kinda misplaced the parameter on the repository